# Integrating SoapUI with JUnit

Tags: junit, soapui

I am trying to integrate SoapUI into my preexisting JUnit tests.  I have created a test in SoapUI 3.6.1.  It works.

My next step is to apply it to my development environment. In my Eclipse project I have added the jar to my classpath. I also created the following test.

```
public class TestMySoapUICase
{

    @Test
    public void testCase() throws Exception
    {
        SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner(); 
        runner.setProjectFile( "test/java/com/path/Test-soapui-project.xml" );
        runner.run();
    }
}
```

This test seems pretty trivial, but I am getting the following exception when running the test as a JUnit test:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLineParser
    at com.path.TestMySoapUICase.testCase(TestMySoapUICase.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

It seems there are other people out there who have had this issue when running the application.  Their solution was to set JAVA_HOME to point at jre6 instead of jre5.  I tried this (not expecting it to work) and, well, was correct; it change nothing.

Does anybody out there have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Add soapui_folder/lib (where so soapui_folder - path to directory with unpacked soapui app) to classpath of your project and you set to go!

WBR

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the commons-cli-1.2.jar file in this project after you also need to add the log4j 1.2.jar