# soapUI and JUnit dependency issue

Tags: maven, junit, soapui

I'm trying to use soapUI integrated to JUnit. I've tried to add the dependencies as mentioned [here](http://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=13463&p=33144&hilit=dependencies#p33144) but it doesn't work. Some classes are not found.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035469/integrating-soapui-with-junit), it is proposed to add the soapui/lib directory to the classpath but this is not really a good practice with Maven.

Do you know which dependency(ies) to add to my project in order to integrate soapUI to JUnit?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do with SoapUI, you may be able to use its Maven plugin, rather than try to integrate it with JUnit: http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html. You can use this to e.g. start a SoapUI mock server, run integration tests that call a web service, then stop the mock server upon completion of the tests. See also the Failsafe plugin if you want to do this.

Failing that, you could add the Maven plugin to your test classpath. This should also pull in all of the dependencies required to run SoapUI itself:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>eviware</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>eviware</id>
    <url>http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an ext folder under your project and add your dependencies there. This is the directory SoapUI runner will look into, for all your external dependencies.

Comment: But I certainly need at least one dependency to compile the unit test classes that use soapUI specific classes? Concerning the ext folder, do you mean that I don't need to add the dependencies in my POM and that soapUI will automatically look for the dependencies in this folder at runtime?

Comment: I think if you are going with maven, you should let soap-ui maven plugin manage your dependencies. However if you have any external dependencies you can add it your plugin tag as dependencies.

Comment: As you said, the soap-ui maven plugin works better than the integration to JUnit in terms of dependencies.