# org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi I am new in automation testing
I am using:

- Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
- Version: Indigo Service Release 2
- Build id: 20120216-1857

And apache maven version: apache-maven-3.0.4

I am facing problem to run automation script through maven and the error is:

```
D:\TestAutomation\MyTestProject_24>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for MyTestProject_24:MyTestProject_24:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.sikuli:sikuli-java:jar should use a variable
instead of a hard-coded path C:\SikuliX\sikuli-java.jar @ line 109, column 18
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missi
ng. @ line 125, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your
    build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyTestProject24 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ MyTestProject_24 ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ MyTestProject_24 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @MyTestProject_24 ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MyTestProject_24 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ MyTestProject_24 ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\TestAutomation\MyTestProject_24\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
    T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.531s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 17 11:41:00 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project MyTestProject_24: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] Cannot instantiate class WebConsoleTest.WebConsoleLoginTest
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:522)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1273)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1260)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1114)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:293)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:91)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBoote
r.java:200)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:
57)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorIm
pl.java:45)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
[ERROR] ... 22 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testlink/api/java/client/TestLinkAPIException
[ERROR] at WebConsoleTest.WebConsoleLoginTest.<init>(WebConsoleLoginTest.java:35)
[ERROR] ... 27 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[ERROR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
[ERROR] ... 28 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following arti
cles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
D:\TestAutomation\MyTestProject_24>
```

And POM.xml is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyTestProject_24</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyTestProject_24</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyTestProject24</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.grid</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-grid-hub</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.28.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.schmizz</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
        <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>  
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikuli-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:\SikuliX\sikuli-java.jar</systemPath>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikuli-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>eviware</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>br.eti.kinoshita</groupId>
                        <artifactId>testlink-java-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.6-1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>      
</project>
```

Comment: Please help me to resolve this error..

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, add the `<version>` tag as shown below:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
    .
    .
    .
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Note - This version number I have extracted from the Maven log that you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added <version> tag in plugin section but still facing same issue.

Comment: Okay. Try with <pluginManagement> tag. Updated answer with this tag.

Comment: I tried with <pluginManagement> tag, but I got error as java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException.

Comment: Good. Your original error (the one mentioned in your question) got fixed! Now issue with SoapUI plugin. This answer might be useful to fix it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618025/soapui-and-junit-dependency-issue

Comment: @Surya - why does this error occur and why can I not ignore it ?

Comment: The <PluginManagement> tag solved plugins warnings in my project. Many Thanks.